# Simple Python code with weird list manipulation/comprehension technique by which one element of the list gets assigned to a variable

Tags: python

Today I was browsing through a coding website and found a simple code in Python which I was having a hard time to comprehend.

Below is the exact code (with extra details added as comments):

```
x = -23 

sign = [1,-1][x < 0] # -1 if x is negative and 1 if x is positive

print(sign) #outputs -1 since x=-23 is negative
```

Can anyone please help me understand how this code is working and what this technique is called (I presume it is some kind of list comprehension/manipulation)?

Comment: FWIW: `from math import copysign; print(copysign(1, x))`…

Comment: I also like `2 * (x >= 0) - 1`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm sure you can come up with some bit shifts if you're aiming for maximum confusion. :D

Comment: @timgeb True, also one of the better ones is `(x >= 0) - (x < 0)`  ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is playing with the fact that [`True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` to `0`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-10).

If `x<0` returns `True`, then `[1,-1][x < 0]` is equivalent to `[1,-1][1]`, and thus `-1`.

The logic is the same when `x<0` returns `False`: `[1,-1][0]` -> `1`

Answer (score 4):

`sign = [1,-1][x < 0]` is just a fancy way to write

```
if x < 0:
    sign = -1
else:
   sign = 1
```

`x < 0` is either `True` or `False`. Since `True == 1` and `False == 0` you can use booleans to index into the list `[-1, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = -23
x2 = 23
sign = ["false","true"][x > 0]
sign2 = ["false","true"][x2 > 0]
print("sign:",sign)
print("sign2:",sign2)
```

the result is sign:false,sign2:true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).